# What does the Hedges g mean in this meta-analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, meta-analysis

I am looking at the outcome scores of the WOMAC for the three studies included in the [meta analysis](https://www.medicaljournals.se/jrm/content/html/10.2340/16501977-2210), but I am having a hard time figuring out what the data means in Table III. Could someone help me figure out how to explain if the WOMAC Scores were improved by the intervention according to Table III and what the significance is of the Hedges g at 6 and 12 weeks? Does this mean the intervention was statistically significant?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can see that table does not report a meta-analysis at all so you just need to look at the means to see the direction of the difference. Is that what you are doubting?

Comment: Yes. I think I am confused because on the studies by McKay and Gstoettner lower scores indicate improvement, but for van Leeuwen higher scores indicate improvement. I just can figure out what that means for when the (-/+) direction of the Hedges g. Does it mean a (-) Hedges g for van Leeuwen favors the control and a (-) Hedges g for the other studies favors the intervention?

Comment: Now , you seem to address another issue.  You have separate issue  in the question. To answer your problem , first try checking how do we conpute Hedges g ?  Just to facilitate  g is statistic computed as difference between scores for TG and CG divided by  pooled S.D. of two groups.

Comment: The numerator for Hedges g is just the treatment mean minus the control mean. However, most people who compute g across studies will ensure that the signs have a consistent meaning across studies. This may require changing to calculated sign when a study has a reserved scale relative to the other studies.